# How do I mock out a Express Response send using Jest and NestJS?

Tags: express, jestjs, nestjs

I have the following code...

```
import { Controller, Get, Header, Res, Req } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Response, Request } from "express";

@Controller("health")
export class HealthController {
  @Get()
  @Header("content-type", "application/json")
  checkHealth(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response): void {
    res.send({
      healthy: true,
    });
  }
}
```

I am trying to unit test (please don't say I should integration test) so I am doing the following...

```
import { Response, Request } from "express";
import { HealthController } from "./health.controller";

describe("Given I am accessing the HealthController", () => {
  let controller: HealthController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    controller = new HealthController();
  });

  describe("findAll", () => {
    it("should return an array of cats", async () => {
      const result = {
        healthy: true,
      };
      const mockCallback = jest.fn((res) =>{
        expect(res).toEqual(result);
      });
      const req = {
      } as Request;
      const res = {
        send: mockCallback,
      } as Response;
      controller.checkHealth(req, res);
      expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

But when I run the test I get....

```
Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0

  25 |       } as Response;
  26 |       controller.checkHealth(req, res);
> 27 |       expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
     |                            ^
  28 |     });
  29 |   });
  30 | });
```

Comment: Test passed on my machine.